# Jpa Specification equivalent for cosmosDb

Tags: java, jpa, azure-cosmosdb, azure-spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate spring boot application from mssql to CosmosDb.

We have the below repository implementation using `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;`  which can fetch data based on any (one or more) columns requested by the user.

```
static Specification<User> isMatching(final Map<String, String> parameters) {
    return new Specification<User>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            parameters.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
                
                predicates.add(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(e.getKey()), e.getValue())));
            });
            return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    };
}
```

and then we are calling this as below:

```
repo.findAll(UserRepo.isMatching(parameters));
```

I had to remove spring-boot-starter-data-jpa from classpath as it will not support CosmosDb. I'm using the below spring and spring data cosmos references in classpath as that is the only combination working for me.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I couldn't really figure out how I can implement the above Specification logic for CosmosDb. I would really appreciate any guidance regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently azure-spring-data-cosmos doesn't provide support for Specification / QueryDSL in azure-spring-data-cosmos SDK. The closest option I can think of is using Criteria API with `SqlQuerySpec`. Using `SqlQuerySpec` you can generate `CosmosQuery` type, which can then be executed using CosmosTemplate or ReactiveCosmosTemplate based on your repository style (sync vs async).

Regarding versioning, I would recommend using the latest version of spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.6.2 and azure-spring-data-cosmos 3.17.0, so that you get the latest features of query annotation as well.

If the `SqlQuerySpec` doesn't work either, alternative would be to get `CosmosClient` bean through `applicationContext` in your spring application, and running the queries directly against azure-cosmos Java v4 SDK, which is used under the hood of our azure-spring-data-cosmos SDK.

Please follow this github issue for any updates on your question - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/25629

Comment: thank you for your response. I actually tried to implement it using SqlQuerySpec and CosmosAsyncClient as below.  

return this.cosmosAsyncClient
                    .getDatabase("user-db")
                    .getContainer("User")
                    .queryItems(new SqlQuerySpec(query, sqlParameters), User.class);

But I couldn't return the Paginated results using the above approach for below method.

Page<User> findAll(Map<String, String> parameters, Pageable pageable);

Comment: 1. Will CosmosQuery support pagination with Pageable parameter? Can you suggest about how to generate CosmosQuery using SqlQuerySpec?
2. Is it possible to return Page<T> using CosmosAsyncClient?
Thanks in advance!